# Angular Form import issue

Tags: angular

i've just imported FormArrray into my app.module, then i ran with ng serve and it gave me this problem.
What Shall I do? installing angular again?
I know, some imports must be deleted, but it's a thing that i prefer to do when the project is ultimated, at least i dont have to keep importing libraries.
I'm also using formControls and formGroups but no one of these gave me any problem, i'm feeling quite dumb .
thank you for the answers and thank you for the help :)

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:1304:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.  

This likely means that the library (@angular/forms) which declares FormArray has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

1304 export declare class FormArray extends AbstractControl {
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstPageComponent } from './first-page/first-page.component';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {HttpClient,HttpClientModule, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpEventType, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormArray
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json

````
  "name": "form-compiler",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Can you also share your `app.module` and your `package.json` files as well?

Comment: i've just updated the post, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported `FormArray` in your module. Just remove that and only include the import in your `component.ts` file only.

Comment: i've already included it also in component but though it was necessary also in module, thank you :))